# ¿Me podrían explicar como podría crear dos arreglos donde imprima la palabra escogida más la abreviatura de esa palabra?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

Al menos este es mi código y me imagino la lógica así, el usuario solo puede ver el arreglo tipo de turismo, yo como programadora soy la única que puedo ver las abreviaturas.

```
cout<<"Tipo de turismo"<<endl;
char* tipoturismo[]={"Volcanes","Playa","Montaña","Aventura"};
char* turismo[]={"Vol","Pla","Mon","Aven"};
for(char turismo=0; turismo<4; turismo++)
{
    cout<<"["<<turismo+1<<"] - "<<tipoturismo[turismo]<<endl;
    cout<<"abreviatura :"<<turismo;
}
```

Pienso almacenar la abreviatura en un archivo de texto, para luego imprimir un listado, para crear un archivo de texto mas comprimido, pero no logro crear una lógica donde relacione ejemplo la opción 1 del arreglo de tipo de turismo con el elemento 1 que seria la abreviatura Vol que es la que tengo que almacenar en mi archivo de texto, ¿me podrían dar una idea de alguna otra forma en la que podría hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos arrays independientes:

```
char* tipoturismo[]={"Volcanes","Playa","Montaña","Aventura"};
char* turismo[]={"Vol","Pla","Mon","Aven"};
```

Los cuales, ya puestos, podrían ser de tipo `string`. Es más sencillo y menos problemático usar `std::string` que `char*`:

```
std::string tipoTurismo[] = {"Volcanes","Playa","Montaña","Aventura"};
std::string turismo[] = {"Vol","Pla","Mon","Aven"};
```

Si te fijas verás que ambos arrays comparten índices, es decir, el primer elemento de `tipoturismo` está relacionado con el primer elemento de `turismo`.

Luego si para acceder al elemento `n` de `tipoturismo` haces:

```
std::cout << tipoturismo[turismo];
```

Para acceder al elemento de `turismo` tendrías que hacer:

```
std::cout << turismo[turismo];
```

Vaya, resulta que tienes dos variables que se llaman exactamente igual:

- El array propiamente dicho
- El contador del bucle

Si dos variables tiene el mismo nombre, solo una de ellas será accesible, la otra quedará *tapada* por la primera.

Procura, por tanto, no solapar los nombres de las variables:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    cout << "["<<i+1<<"] - " << tipoturismo[i] << '\n';
    cout << "abreviatura :" << turismo[i];
}
```

Ahora ya sí

Comment: gracias @eferion me ayudo mas tu sintaxis simple la verdad

Comment: @EstherPorta aunque esta solución te haya sido de más utilidad, si crees que otras solución te han aportado algo de utilidad, estaría bien que las votases con un positivo+

Comment: ok no sabia que eso se podia hacer

Answer (score 2):

> pero no logro crear una lógica donde relacione ejemplo la opción 1 del arreglo
> de tipo de turismo con el elemento 1 que seria la abreviatura Vol que es la
> que tengo que almacenar en mi archivo de texto, me podrían dar una idea de
> alguna otra forma en la que podría hacer esto?

Si lo que quieres es formar una relaciones 1 a 1, lo mejor que puedes utilizar
es `std::map` o `std::unordered_map`. Segun yo entinedo, tu quieres dar la
abreviacion y obtener la palabra completa, eso lo puedes hacer de la siguiente
forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> palabras = {
        {"Vol", "Volcanes"},
        {"Pla", "Playa"},
        {"Mon", "Montaña"},
        {"Aven", "Aventura"},
    };

    std::cout << palabras.at("Vol") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda @Pablochaches pero me ayudo mas la sintaxis mas simple de eferion, me costo mucho entender tu sintaxis, igualmente gracias por tu comentario